Sentence structure and modal verbs

I can always rely on him

I always can rely on him


As I understand it both are fine but 1 is standard. 2 is non-standard emphasizing different things, still correct?

One is standard but the other could be for how fast you want the always to appear.

If you want to sound like a native English speaker, you will say:

I can always rely on him.

"I always can rely on him" is awkward and would only really be appropriate in a very specific situation where the emphasis of the sentence is always rather than rely.

OP's two sentences:


I can always rely on him.
I always can rely on him.


Here only sentence 1 is grammatically correct. Only in poems can you use a sentence like this. Poetic licence allows poet to bend grammatical rules.
So in poems you can write:

I always can rely
Always can I rely
Rely on him can I always.


#3 is surely only correct if you're Yoda: Strong with that one, the force is.
